# merge two files with two common fields

Tags: command-line, text-processing

File1

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF_Zv  ALT_lm                             
chr1A   219620  .       T       A
chr1A   219648  .       A       G
chr1A   219867  .       A       G
```

file2

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF_Zv  ALT_RV                             
chr1A   219457  .       C       T
chr1A   219670  .       A       G
chr1A   219867  .       A       C
```

File3

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF_Zv  ALT_lm ALT_RV                            
chr1A   219620  .       T       A    NA
chr1A   219648  .       A       G    NA
chr1A   219867  .       A       G    C
chr1A   219457  .       C       NA   T
chr1A   219670  .       A       NA   C
```

My command is

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} {if(a[$1,$2]==""){a[$1,$2]=0};print \
$1,$2,$3,$4,$5, a[$4,$5]} ' file1 file2 > file3
```

However,
I can not get the file3 which I want.
Could you help me improve the command?

Thanks,
Fuyou

Comment: Good question, I've just fixed some formatting for you - you paste preformatted code by indenting it with 4 spaces (there's a `{}` button that does this on the enhanced editor)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to explain how and based on what the records are supposed to be merged? What exactly is the given Awk program supposed to achieve? Are other text processing tools (e. g. Perl or Python) an option or do you need or prefer an Awk solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this on-the-fly in a single pass - you either need to save the indexed `ALT_lm` and `ALT_RV` values and merge/print them in an `END` block (in which case it will be hard to preserve the original order - if that matters), or make two passes over one of the files: for example (ugly - and requires GNU Awk):

```
$ gawk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS="\t";
    print "#CHROM","POS","ID","REF_Zv","ALT_lm","ALT_RV";
  } 
  BEGINFILE { fn++ }
  FNR == 1 {next}
  fn == 1 {ALT_RV[$1 FS $2] = $5; next} 
  fn == 2 {ALT_lm[$1 FS $2] = $5;}
  {   
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($1 FS $2) in ALT_lm ? ALT_lm[$1 FS $2] : "NA", ($1 FS $2) in ALT_RV ? ALT_RV[$1 FS $2] : "NA";
  }' file2 file1 file2
#CHROM  POS ID  REF_Zv  ALT_lm  ALT_RV
chr1A   219620  .   T   A   NA
chr1A   219648  .   A   G   NA
chr1A   219867  .   A   G   C
chr1A   219457  .   C   NA  T
chr1A   219670  .   A   NA  G
chr1A   219867  .   A   G   C
```